# What is the relation/difference between "Package Manager" or "Package Management"?

Tags: apt, software-installation, package-management, repository, dnf

I read in many tutorials about `apt` and `dnf` and *others* where the *"Package Manager"* and *"Package Management"* terms are used - ***but just being curious***:

- What is the relation/difference between *"Package Manager"* or *"Package Management"*?

Does it exist? Or consider the same question rephrased as:

- What is the official term *"Package Manager"* or *"Package Management"*?

Or it does not matter? which term is preferred? Perhaps there is a slight difference to be take it in consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the official term "Package Manager" or "Package Management"?

You can use either depending on what you're trying to convey.

If need to *install/remove/upgrade* a package you use the *package manager*, e.g. `apt` or `dnf` (there are others as well).

If you want to talk about the issues of using `apt` or `dnf`, you could say "Package management in Linux is not without issues".

IMO it doesn't really matter and you could say what you like, e.g. "I'll now run a package manager" or "I'll perform package management".

> Perhaps there is a slight difference to be take it in consideration.

Nothing that I can think of except their innate meaning: one is a tool, another one is a process.